# Aggregating JSON object in Dataframe and converting string timestamp to date

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I got JSON rows that looks like the following

```
    [{"time":"2017-03-23T12:23:05","user":"randomUser","action":"sleeping"}]
    [{"time":"2017-03-23T12:24:05","user":"randomUser","action":"sleeping"}]
    [{"time":"2017-03-23T12:33:05","user":"randomUser","action":"sleeping"}]
    [{"time":"2017-03-23T15:33:05","user":"randomUser2","action":"eating"}]
    [{"time":"2017-03-23T15:33:06","user":"randomUser2","action":"eating"}]
```

So I got 2 problem, First of all the time is stored as String inside my df, I believe it has to be date for me to aggregate them?

second of all, I need to aggregate those datas by 5 minutes interval,
just for example everything that happens from 2017-03-23T12:20:00 to 2017-03-23T12:24:59 need to be aggregated and considered as 2017-03-23T12:20:00 timestamp

expected output is

```
    [{"time":"2017-03-23T12:20:00","user":"randomUser","action":"sleeping","count":2}]
    [{"time":"2017-03-23T12:30:00","user":"randomUser","action":"sleeping","count":1}]
    [{"time":"2017-03-23T15:30:00","user":"randomUser2","action":"eating","count":2}]
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the `StringType` column into a `TimestampType` column using casting; Then, you can cast the timestamp into `IntegerType` to make the "rounding" down to the last 5-minute interval easier, and group by that (and all other columns):

```
// importing SparkSession's implicits
import spark.implicits._

// Use casting to convert String into Timestamp:
val withTime = df.withColumn("time", $"time" cast TimestampType)

// calculate the "most recent 5-minute-round time" and group by all
val result = withTime.withColumn("time", $"time" cast IntegerType)
  .withColumn("time", ($"time" - ($"time" mod 60 * 5)) cast TimestampType)
  .groupBy("time", "user", "action").count()

result.show(truncate = false)
// +---------------------+-----------+--------+-----+
// |time                 |user       |action  |count|
// +---------------------+-----------+--------+-----+
// |2017-03-23 12:20:00.0|randomUser |sleeping|2    |
// |2017-03-23 15:30:00.0|randomUser2|eating  |2    |
// |2017-03-23 12:30:00.0|randomUser |sleeping|1    |
// +---------------------+-----------+--------+-----+
```